# wikipedias API search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, wikipedia

id like to create multiple div elements with at least 10 results from the wikipedia api ajax request. I think i have the query correct but when it comes to initiliazing my values they end up as undefined. here is my code:

```
$('#inputBar input').val(textVal);
$.ajax( {
            url : "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch="+textVal+"&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(parsed_json){

                  var title = parsed_json['query']['search']['title'];
                  var description = parsed_json['query']['search']['extract']
                  var url = parsed_json['query']['search']['source']
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){

                    $('.results').append('<div class="result col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><h2>"+title+"</h2><p>"+description+"</p></div>');
                }
              }
          } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to things that don't exist in the `parsed_json` variable.

It should be `parsed_json.query.pages.title` (and the same with the others)